# How to insert data into a pivot table with columns belonging to same model in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a **Block** model which is basically for blocked users. It has a `target_id` and a `sender_id`, both of which are IDs from the *users* table. How can I add data to this pivot table when a user wants to block another user? What should my relationship methods look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both **target_id** and **sender_id** are fields from the `users` table, your relationship must be defined this way.

```
class User {

  public function blocks() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','blocked_users','sender_id','target_id')->withPivot(['id']);
   }

  public function blockedBy() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','blocked_users','target_id','sender_id')->withPivot(['id']);
   }

}
```

Here `blocked_users` is the name of the table.

So, to block a user you can do :-

```
//User who is going to block
$user = User::find($id);
$inputs = [$target_user_id];
$user->blocks()->attach($inputs);

//or you can use,
$user->blocks()->sync($inputs, false);
```

The false in the above sync is used when the old synced rows are ignored and new ones are attached.

To get the list of users who that particular user has blocked, you can do :-

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->blocks;
```

And to get the list of users who that particular user is blocked by

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->blockedBy;
```

Thanks,